# is it possible to determine the Animation Order

Tags: ios, core-animation, caanimation, cabasicanimation

I have three animations. But I want to play these respectively, not at the same time. All of animations are instance of `CABasicAnimation`. How can i achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Sequential / Chained / "One after another" CAAnimations has been asked for many times before. As the [FAQ] says: "Please [look around](http://stackoverflow.com/search) to see if your question has been asked before."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `CABasicAnimation` is a subclass of `CAAnimation`. `CAAnimation` has a `delegate` property. This delegate is called with

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
```

when one animation did stop (either forced or finished).

So set your `CABasicAnimation` delegate and implement the `animationDidStop:finished:` delegate method, check that the animation has finished

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
{
  if (theAnimation == myFirstAnimation)
     if (flag)
         {}
     } 
  }
}
```

and you are good to go.